# Transaction Isolation Level issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, isolation-level

I have been reading up on Transaction Isolation Levels and I am not sure I understand everything correctly. I need help.

Please consider the following Csharp pseudo code:

1. Using Stored procedure 1, open transaction
2. Insert or update table 1
3. Using Stored procedure 2, insert or update table 2, based on data on table 1
4. Commit transaction.

In step 3, how can I not consider the data that has been updated in step 2? Should I set a Transaction Isolation Level when I am creating a transaction in my .Net code. Here is the SQL server stored procedure pseudo code.

```
select @count=count(*) from table1;
if @count > 1
update table2
```

Comment: To clarify; you want step 3 to see the data in table 1 as it was before step 2?

Comment: @DanDef: At a 10,000 feet level, that true. On a 100 feet level, step 3 does much much more and therefore the sequence of the steps cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Just changing the order doesn't solve your problem? I mean, if Step 2 changes Table 1 data, and you need it intact to execute Step 3, execute Step 3 first. It would look like this:

1. Open Transaction
2. Execute Procedure 2
3. Execute Procedure 1
4. Close Transaction

---

Considering what you just commented, you would probably need to use *IsolationLevel.Snapshot*. However, **some databases don't have this enabled by default**. It basically created a copy of the current data to tempdb when you update the source table.

Comment: At a 10,000 feet level, you are right. On a 100 feet level, step 3 does much much more and therefore the sequence of the steps cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, none of the isolation levels allow you to access previous versions of a row once they have been modified.

To achieve what you are asking, you will need to modify step 2 to keep track of what it has changed and make it available to step 3. Otherwise, you will need to add triggers to the tables modified in step 2 and track the changes that way.